# bind「systemctl start named」エラー

Tags: dns

CentOS7にbindをインストールし、`systemctl start named` でサービス起動しようとしたところ、以下のメッセージが出力されました。原因/対処を教えて下さい。

```
[root@centos etc]# systemctl start named
Job for named.service failed because the control process exited
with error code. See "systemctl status named.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

service named status」コマンド実行結果とnamed.confの設定は、以下の通りです。
すいません、どこが原因か分からず、ご教示をお願いします。

★「service named status」コマンド実行結果

```
[root@centos ~]# service named status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 土 2021-12-25 14:58:19 JST; 3min 5s ago
  Process: 2894 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 2892 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: binding TCP socket: address in use
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: listening on IPv6 interface lo, ::1#53
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: binding TCP socket: address in use
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: unable to listen on any configured interfaces
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: loading configuration: failure
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain named[2896]: exiting (due to fatal error)
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: named.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit named.service entered failed state.
12月 25 14:58:19 centos.localdomain systemd[1]: named.service failed.
```

★/etc/named.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;192.168.23.141; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any;};

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;192.168.23.141; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
        secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
        allow-query     { any;};

        /*
         - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
         - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable
           recursion.
         - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access
           control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
           cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification
           attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
           reduce such attack surface
        */
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

        pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
        session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "test.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "test.com.zone";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
#include "/var/named/test.com.zone";
```

Comment: 「エラーが出た」で終わらず、まずはエラーメッセージを読みましょう。表示されている通り、`systemctl status named.service` や `journalctl -xe` を実行することで状況を確認してみてください。